# What is the correct way to implement meta-transactions for OpenSea using Polygon?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, polygon, opensea, meta-transactions

OpenSea documentation provides differing information on how to implement meta-transactions:

The [code snippet OpenSea has under "Meta-transactions"](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/polygon-basic-integration) shows the contract inheriting `ERC721`, `ContextMixin`, and `ERC2771Context`.

But the link on that page to "Sample implementations" shows [the contract](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/meta-transactions/blob/main/contracts/ERC721MetaTransactionMaticSample.sol) inheriting `ERC721`, `ContextMixin`, and `NativeMetaTransaction`.

Are both ways compatible with OpenSea?

(If using `ERC2771Context`, is there anything additional that needs to be done, such as passing `ERC2771Context` the address of a trusted forwarder?)

Answer (score 0):

OpenSea gave me this answer to the question:

> I've checked in with our developers and they've let me know both
> examples you've provided should work; the code detailed in our
> developer docs was written more recently, however they personally know
> the code detailed in github works and would recommend that route.

> Furthermore, in the github example the custom contract you've created
> is the forwarder, but if you choose to use the developer docs, you can
> use your contract as the forwarder there as well.